# Is there a way to change the on-screen position of the 'Return' button on my Archos 101?

Tags: buttons, archos-101

I have bought an Archos 101 tablet.

It doesn't have hard buttons, but in stead, **on screen buttons** for '*Return*', '*Home*', '*Menu*' and '*Help*'.

If I hold the tablet in an **horizontal position** (*landscape mode*), the 4 four buttons are displayed at the **right edge of the screen**, with the '*Return*' button at the bottom ( and the 3 other buttons on top of 'Return' in the order given above.

So **I have to use my right hand** to press the '*Return*' button. Being right handed, this is a natural place for the 'Return' button to be situated (lower right corner of the screen)T - after all, it's the button you use the most.

However, when I hold the tablet in a **vertical position** (*portrait mode*), the 4 buttons are displayed at the **bottom of the screen**, in exact the same order : from left to right '*Return*', '*Home*', '*Menu*' and '*Help*'.

This now means that **I have to use my LEFT hand** to press the '*Return*' button.

---

**I would like to still use my right hand to press the '*Return*' key.**

---

Therefore my question: **is it possible to change the order of the 4 on screen buttons on an Archos 101 tablet ?**

Answer (score 1):

in the google market there is an app to change the archos buttons and even add some. its named archos buttons afaik. but your device has to be rooted. havent tested it though.

Comment: This answer had a down vote, which I don't understand (no explanation was given by the down voter - which I find rude - especially for down votes on answers of new forum members). The program actually exists in the market and it does what I am asking for. Problem is: I don't want to root my device. I upvoted this anwswer since I did not explicitly stated that I did not want to root my device.

Comment: Don't think its possible without root. Which one of the 101 tablet do you have? There are one with android 2.2 and one with Honeycomb...

Comment: As the link is missing: you probably mean [Buttons for RW Rooted Archos](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.pruss.archosbuttons&rdid=mobi.pruss.archosbuttons)?